# Can I somehow share the pristines folder across multiple checkouts of the same codebase?

Tags: svn

I like that Subversion 1.7 now has all the pristines in one place for a working copy.  However, I often have several checkouts of the same codebase (largely to replicate the stash function that doesn't exist yet).

To save disk space, is there any way to combine all these pristine folders, so I don't have multiple clean copies?  In particular:

1. Is it unsafe to have "extra" clean files in there, that aren't base copies of any of the currently checked-out files
2. Can this be done using links somehow, especially on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked in Dmitry's answer, but I think there's an easier way, which is using hard links on the files in the pristine directories.  Then deletion of one version of the file doesn't affect the other copies.  The downside is many tools (eg, backup software) will still backup the pristines multiple times, but my main disk isn't eaten up as much.

Also, I've learned from this that running svn cleanup occasionally can save a lot of local disk space if you have big changes!

In summary, my svnclone.bat looks roughly like this:

```
robocopy /E %1 %2 /XD .svn
robocopy /E %1\.svn %2\.svn /XD pristine
ln -r %1\.svn\pristine %2\.svn\pristine
```

This is much quicker than a straight copy as well.

The downside is that over time, if these clones are long-lived, then duplicates will appear.  But I think for my usage it's good enough.

The ln.exe is from http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot do that. SVN counts references number to each pristine file. If it reaches zero, "svn cleanup" remove those files.

On the other hand you may try a hacky way for SVN 1.7.5 (on your own risk! I can't guarantee that further SVN versions will be compatible with these hacks; and I didn't try it, but to my knowledge how SVN works, this should work with 1.7.5):

1. Set 'refcount' to a higher value to prevent checksums from removal for all working copies (you should do that before every "svn cleanup" call --- to update 'refcount' for newly installed pristine files):

   sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "update PRISTINE set refcount=refcount+100;"
2. Windows supports links, though they are not so popular:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link  At least they work fine for me even in XP.

So the hacky way is to create a directory, collect all pristine files in it (maybe with a script). Make links at .svn/pristine pointing to that directory. Run that SQL command above and run before every "svn cleanup".

And I can also provide an algorithm how to repair from that configuration back to normal (if anything goes wrong).

1. Remove links .svn/pristine, replace them with empty directories or (better and faster) with copies of contents of that directory with all pristine directory.
2. Repair working copy with SmartSVN like in this article: http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/06/20/missing-pristines-in-svn-working-copy/ (at also explains what happens if 'refcount' becomes zero)

Good luck:)